# Updating models with unique fields in Django using ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I get "value already exist" error when I try to update the existing record.

**example:**
    I have 5 products defined in the database. Now I want to edit the 4th record. I call the "product_edit" with the pk value. Now, I am changing the product name field and leave the product number field unchanged. When I hit submit, an error message is displayed above the product number input field. "Product with this Product Number already exists". How can I avoid this?

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
productname = models.CharField("Product Name", max_length=200, unique=True)
productnumber = models.CharField("Product Number", max_length=50, unique=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.productname
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['productname', 'productnumber']
```

**views.py**

```
def product_edit(request, pk, template_name='dictionary/prod/prod_add.html'):
product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, instance=product)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('dictionary/prod/prod_list.html')
return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.product_edit, name='product_edit'),
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: @erthalion, I have added an example. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's very strange, because your code seems right. Can you show select * from product table?

Comment: @Eugene Soldatov, SELECT * FROM TABLE gives a table of data with three columns (id-pk), (productname) and (productnumber).

Comment: I mean data from table, not structure.

Comment: 8;"King Pin";"84579"
5;"SMPT";"1255668"
1;"TRRP";"5216358"
3;"GINT";"845796"
4;"RPTL";"8598674"

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Maybe something wrong in the view? Is the ``pk`` variable not ``none`` and correct? In the ``urls.py`` ``pk`` defined as named, but in the view it has been used as normal argument.

Comment: pk value is not null. I ensured that pk value is getting passed to the url and view. I can say this because I get the Form html with relevant values filled in for editing. I can't understand the normal argument that you had mentioned above. Please elaborate.

Comment: @erthalion, your trigger on views made me to rewrite the views and html. That solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Changed pk to id in views, created a new update.html for update. Left the form action url empty as it is populated by and submitted to the same view.